# Regular Expression to fetch repeating group

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text from which I need to retrieve specific information(could be multiline):

```
Type [Hello] Server [serverName]. [BC]. [CD] [D" +
                "E]. [FH]. [MN]. [CS]., ID = 53ec9d"
```

From the text i need to retrieve:

`serverName` and the following entries within `[]` which care seperated by `" ."`. They can repeat any number of times. Their ending is denoted by `".,".`

So in above case my output should be :

`serverName : serverName`

and values should be:

```
BC , CD, DE,FH, MN,CS
```

Need help on the requirement.

Comment: Did you forget a `.` after `[CD]`?

Comment: What's your approach? Share your attempts with us so you can get a better help.

Comment: what's with [D" + "E]

Comment: How are you getting your input text?

Answer (score 0):

For the idea run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Type [Hello] Server [serverName]. [BC]. [CD] [DE]. [FH]. [MN]. [CS]., ID = 53ec9d";

    /*
     * anything that is surrounded by [ ] characters and doesn't contain [ ]
     */
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[\\]]+)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(s);

    boolean first = true, second = true;
    while (matcher.find()) {

        if (first) { // avoiding [Hello]
            first = false;
            continue;
        }

        // remove surrounding [ ]
        String currentValue = matcher.group(1).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");

        // first find is treated differently
        if (second) {
            second = false;
            System.out.println("serverName = " + currentValue);
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println(currentValue);
    }
}
```

output is:

```
serverName = serverName
BC
CD
DE
FH
MN
CS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.,.*$|Server\s*\[([^\]]*)|\.\s+\[([^\]]*)
```

You can try this.See demo.Grab the captures.

http://regex101.com/r/rA7aS3/5